# Auto-snip with snipping tool Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, snipping

I would like to use Windows Snipping tool in a simple matter: When I start the program I want it to **automaticly start a rectangular snip**.

*I am using Windows 8. When I used the same program in Windows 7, I could do it.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was changed in Windows 8:

MSFT answered it here on channel9:

**Defrag: Deprecated HW, Deleted Partition, Disabling Right Click Animation**
http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/The-Defrag-Show/Defrag-Deprecated-HW-Deleted-Partition-Disabling-Right-Click-Animation

[13:50](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/The-Defrag-Show/Defrag-Deprecated-HW-Deleted-Partition-Disabling-Right-Click-Animation#time=13m50s)- Is there a way to make Snipping Tool in Win8 active on launch.

MSFT says it was changed on customers feedback.

Comment: Thanks that answers my question 100%! :) 
Now I have to download another snipping tool with this feature.

Comment: if you use autohotkey you can still use it with the hack I've posted

Answer (score 4):

I used a simple [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script to emulate what the Windows 7 version did.

```
#s::
Run, "C:\windows\system32\SnippingTool.exe"
WinWaitActive, ahk_class Microsoft-Windows-Tablet-SnipperToolbar
{
    send ^{PrintScreen}
}
return
```

Note `#s` (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>) shortcut can be anything you choose. Like all AHK scripts you want running all the time, add it to the startup folder.

Comment: I tried this out (Win10) and it will launch the snipping tool but it starts inactive. As soon as I click the window to make it active it sends the Control+PrintScreen key combo, but that isn't the same as it was working before in Win7.  I added: `WinWait, ahk_class Microsoft-Windows-Tablet-SnipperToolbar` and `WinActivate, ahk_class Microsoft-Windows-Tablet-SnipperToolbar`


and seems to now work as I was looking for; I could probably remove the `WinWaitActive` call but I just left it in.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted exactly what the OP did and the above AHK script just grabs the whole window in a screenshot.  This AHK script binds win+s to start the snipping tool and automatically starts a rectangular snip on launch...

```
#s::
Run, "C:\windows\system32\SnippingTool.exe"
WinWait, ahk_class Microsoft-Windows-Tablet-SnipperToolbar
WinActivate, ahk_class Microsoft-Windows-Tablet-SnipperToolbar
WinWaitActive, ahk_class Microsoft-Windows-Tablet-SnipperToolbar
{
    Send !n
    Send {Down}
    Send {Down}
    Send {Enter}


}
return
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the answers here, you could use the FOSS [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/) instead and map a particular shortcut to region snipping.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to achieve that with [Microsoft Windows Power-Toys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys), pressing <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, opens the snipping tool, which is more powerful the built-in Windows snipping tool.